# Can't find my file with with open(filename, 'w') on Windows

Tags: python

I'm studying python at school and I would like to test some scripts.
However, the computers at school use Linux but at home I use Windows.
I find my solution to practice at home but at least, my only problem is when I use **with open** to create a file in Python.

The program works fine because I verify the correction at school but I can't find my file on my computer.

The program I work on is to clean a text without space or "#" so I just put the list lines here :

```
with open(deck, 'r') as data: 
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as output: 
        for line in data: 
            if (not ligne_commentee(line)) and (not ligne_vide(line)):
                output.write(supprime_caracteres_commentes(line))
```

PS : I'm french, so the names of the file are in french...

Deck is `deck = "C:\Users\CHLOE\Desktop\mes\texte_test.txt"`.

This is how I can read my file but I don't find a solution to find the find I create with `output.write()`.

Can you help me ? Thank you !

Comment: On windows try '/' or '\\' instead of '\' in pathing.

Comment: @Johnnymopp how do you know that the OP didn't type  a single '\' instead '\\' as your edit suggest?

Comment: Try using a full path for the output file and make sure it is a folder you have permission to write to.

Comment: @ScottBoston I just put that in backticks - I did not modify the text. Either the `\\\` were already there, or the SO editor added them.

Comment: Have you checked your current working directory for the file? `os.getcwd()`

Comment: @Engineero, it's not necessary that the file exists. If it does not - it will be created. The problem most probably is the way OP writes the path with single backslash as suggested by Scott Boston. And the output.txt is in the current working directory.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't specify an absolute path for `output` like you did with `deck`, Python creates `output.txt` based on your current directory (which will always differ based on where you are running the script).

Put in an absolute path for `output.txt`:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\CHLOE\\Desktop\\mes\\output.txt', 'w') as output: 

# ... rest of your code
```

If `output.txt` is always relative to your `deck` input, you can also do this:

```
import os

output_path = os.path.dirname(deck)
with open(deck, 'r') as data: 
    with open(os.path.join(output_path, 'output.txt'), 'w') as output:

# ... rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank for the answer ! That doing nothing :/ The terminal runs normaly but when I look in my directory "mes", nothing appared

Comment: Then your condition `if (not ligne_commentee(line)) and (not ligne_vide(line))` simply wasn't triggered because it wasn't `True`.  You can easily test this by removing the condition and just `output.write("test")` and you should see the file created.

Comment: If that is the case then your problem is not with the `output.txt`, but the condition.  You will need to give us more information on what are `ligne_commentee()` and `ligne_vide()` preferrably in a [MCVE] format to diagnose your problem.

Comment: deck is not refering to output.txt I use "deck"  to read a file containing an adn sequence and I want to put in output.txt the cleaning of the sequence

Comment: All the program is : def supprime_caracteres_commentes(ligne):
    if ligne.find('#') == -1:
        return ligne
    else:
        return ligne.split('#')[0] + '\n';

def ligne_commentee(ligne):
    ligne = ligne.lstrip()
    if ligne.find('#') == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def ligne_vide(ligne):
    ligne = ligne.strip()
    if len(ligne) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

Comment: I understand `deck` is the "read" file, have you tried simply writing something under `output.txt` without a condition and still don't see it being created? Also your `ligne_commentee()` function seems to be doing the reverse - if there is no `"#"` in the line, it returns `True`? Which means each line that is *not* a comment will return `False` at `(not ligne_commentee(line))` condition.  You only wanted the comments in your `output`?

Comment: I try to replace with output.write("test") but nothing appared too :/ I try this script at school and it was okay, I got a script with my DNA but here, I try differents methods and nothing :/ I don't understand why, even if we give the direction of the file, it creates nothing I'm very sorry :/ Oh no ! I didn't see this error : I want to delete my commented line ! I changed that !

Comment: Perhaps it will help to update your question with a [MCVE] of your current code, including the definition of `ligne_commentee` and `ligne_vide` as well as `deck` to see where things went wrong.  You don't need to be sorry, just help us help you.

Comment: Also did you already use double backslash `\\ ` per the comments? Single backslash `\ ` will surely give your code problems.

Comment: nothing better then read this medium post: https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f there you will learn how to handle file strings on all file systems